# Why aren't my inputs triggering exceptions in my properties

Tags: python, exception

Whenever I run the code with my exceptions and test the exceptions they never get triggered I ran it with the "raise exception tag" and now im trying it with "assert" but it still is not working.

```py
class Country:

  #initializes a new instance of the country class
  def __init__(self):
    self._country_code = ""
    self._country_name = ""
   

  @property
  def country_code(self):
    return self._country_code

    #getter for country code

  @country_code.setter
  def country_code(self, country_code):
    assert (len(country_code)) > 3

      # makes sure that the country code is only set to 3 characters long

    self._country_code = country_code
    # setter for country code

  @property
  def country_name(self):
    return self._country_name

    #getter for country name

  @country_name.setter
  def country_name(self, country_name):
    assert country_name[0].upper() > 'U'
      
    self._country_name = country_name
```

This is the program which calls for inputs:

```py
from Country import Country

def main():
  
  c = Country()

  c._country_code = input("What is your country code? \n")
  c._country_name = input("What is the name of your country? \n")

  print ("Country code: " + c._country_code)
  print ("Country name: " + c._country_name)
```

Comment: `assert (len(country_code)) > 3`, if the assertion is `False`, an exception will be raised. However if `len(country_code) > 3` no exception will be raised as that is True.

Comment: You're assigning to the internal attributes, which bypasses the setters, so the `assert` statements are never executed.

Comment: `assert` should not be used for input validation, since it doesn't do anything when debugging is disabled. It's intended for verifying the correctness of code.

Comment: @Barmar when I used to have an if statement with a raise exception() statement it wouldnt run either with the property decoration. if I ran normal getters and setters it would work. How would I put it so they dont get bypassed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here

```
  c._country_code = input("What is your country code? \n")
  c._country_name = input("What is the name of your country? \n")
```

You aren't actually calling any setter, you are just assigning to c variables directly. Change it to

```
  c.country_code = input("What is your country code? \n")
  c.country_name = input("What is the name of your country? \n")
```

and it should work

Comment: AHHH that worked. I was banging my head over a stupid _ lol. Thanks!